# GPL covers the linguistic data in *spell dictionaries?

Tags: licensing, gpl, bsd-license

There are good annotated vocabulary in {a,i,my}spell dictionaries, giving the lexical class et all.

I'm writing a program that  needs a large vocabulary, but with a reduced scope, so I don't need all the information on the *spell dictionaries. Then, I'm reading this dictionary data, processing it and rewriting in my own format.
The dictionary I'm using is GPLv2 and I want to release my program in BSD.

As the data itself [the idiom] is public domain, but the representation of data [*spell .dic files] is not, maybe I must follow GPL.

But as I'm not using the GPLd code itself, but a derived trough machine processing from it, maybe I must not.

**Additional info:**

I'm already making my derived own word list, mostly because the original word list have too much semantic information, like this: 
`"ripostar/#vi/XYL/"` or `"ritualizar/#vt/XYPLnc/"`.
But the resulting world list must be manually curated afterwards. This lead to a situation where I will distribute my word list and not require the original to works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licenses and intellectual property. It should be addressed to a lawyer.

Comment: I disagree, @MainMa. Licensing in [on topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and this can be applied to all programmers wanting to write a program that needs a corpus of human language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its fuzzy.  You're going to need to talk to someone who is familiar with the intellectual property of copyrights and word lists in your jurisdiction.

Lists of facts doesn't enjoy copyright in the United States.  The court case for this is [Feist v. Rural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_v._Rural) where it was ruled that copyrightability is based on originality.  In this case, a collection of phone numbers doesn't meet that threshold of originality.

Note that in *other* countries the governing principle is [sweat of the brow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat_of_the_brow).

Word lists themselves are hazy.  Scrabble has some [history](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/gaming/2014/09/major_scrabble_brouhaha_can_you_copyright_a_list_of_words.html) about a particular word list and who owns it - is the selection of words minimally creative? or is it a rote compilation?  I don't know.  I can't really say.  You could argue it either way.  If it isn't protectable by copyright, then the word list isn't able to be licensed... though that does get back into the protected by copyright ***where*** aspect.

For this, your best bet would to contact an organization that can answer some questions about the GPL.  From http://www.fsf.org/about/contact/email

> **For any questions about the GNU GPL, LGPL, AGPL and Free Documentation Licenses:**
>   licensing@fsf.org

And they would be able to give you about as an authoritative answer you can get before you start paying money to a lawyer.

You may also wish to consider the *format* of the file being something that is open.  Write a program that can handle any {a,i,my}spell dictionary format.  Just don't include the GPL files with it.  Include a minimally useful dictionary with it.  Other people can use other dictionaries if they so desire.

You may find [other word lists](https://github.com/kevina/wordlist) that have a BSD compatible license.

Comment: Source ports of old games such as Doom or Quake have precedent for your last point about the format of the file. Source ports typically assume the original game files are already installed. While the code may be open, sometimes the artwork and other assets are not. This is a similar problem to this question: how do I write a program that uses data I may not have the rights to distribute with my program?

Comment: I can't use the source port solution, @Snowman because my version of the dictionaries need to be manually curated before distribution.

Comment: You make me research a little about the Brazilian law, @MicaelIT, and [here](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9610.htm): Art. 8º Are not protected by copyright: 
V - the  common use information, like calendars, schedules, records or captions.  As the list of words with the syntax information annotated is probably a "common use information", this content must be, by law, public domain in Brasil. But it's not like I'm fearing the law. I just want to do the right thing.

Comment: @Cochise the thing with copyright is that its internationally accepted [that if its copyrighted in one place, its recognized in the others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention).  If the word list was compiled in England, even though it wouldn't be copyrightable in the US, it would still be honored as copyrighted because it was in a place where it could be. It gets to be a mess. One of the reasons you should check with lawyers when its reasonable to do so.

Comment: @MichaelT most of pt aspell is from Portugal, a project of Minho University. Lets see what the Portuguese law says. And most FLOSS hosts are from US. And the library can be used on Angola or any other seven countries that spoke Portuguese, or by a immigrant in any place on world. Yes, it will be a mess.

Comment: Digging a little bit, the Portuguese (Brazilian) Dictionary in http://www.altova.com/dictionaries/ is under the LGPL which would appear to allow a combined works. I'm not sure how it would apply to a word list rather than a library. If you can find [Project Natura](https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Dictionaries#Portuguese) wordlist, the MPL or original BSD licensing would likely be compatible with your project.

Comment: @MichaelT I don't think the Berne Convention extends copyright protection to the US in that case. Under 17 USC 104, it seems that copyright protection in the US is because being a citizen of a Berne party or publishing in a party is treated like being a US citizen or publishing in the US; protection cannot come from the Berne Convention alone. IANAL, but that seems to mean that something that isn't copyrightable if published in the US can't have copyright enforced on it through the Berne Convention (note: this sort of thing is why OP should see a lawyer).

Answer (score 3):

The following is from the "Copyright" file included in the [Aspell distribution](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/):

> This English word list is comes directly from [SCOWL 7.0](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=SCOWL) (up to level
>   60, using the speller/make-aspell-dict script,
>   http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)  and is thus under the same
>   copyright of SCOWL.  The affix file (only included in the aspell6
>   package) is based on the Ispell one which is under the same copyright
>   of Ispell.  Part of SCOWL is also based on Ispell thus the Ispell
>   copyright is included with the SCOWL copyright.
>
> The collective work is Copyright 2000-2011 by Kevin Atkinson as well
>   as any of the copyrights mentioned below:

This specifies the origins of the files. It then goes on to state in no uncertain terms that what you are trying to do is explicitly allowed (emphasis added):

> Copyright 2000-2011 by Kevin Atkinson
>
> **Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute and sell these word
>
>   lists**, the associated scripts, the output created from the scripts,
>   and its documentation for any purpose **is hereby granted without fee,
>
>   provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
>
>   that both that copyright notice and this permission notice appear in
>
>   supporting documentation.** Kevin Atkinson makes no representations
>   about the suitability of this array for any purpose. It is provided
>   "as is" without express or implied warranty.

I admit that I had to dig for this info. It was not listed on the web site directly, but I figured it would be in the distribution files somewhere. That really is the authoritative place that has to contain copyright and license details.

Comment: Thanks. That is a very good answer, but sadly at the moment I'm not working with English dictionaries, but Portuguese. Those don't have license explanation as good the English one, and simply says "This program is free and can be redistributed and/or modified in the terms of LGPLv2.1" I will address the question to the developers. I think they will have the final word in this topic of wordlists.

Answer (score 1):

So what’s your question? Would your work count as a derivative work from (*work based on*) a dictionary or not?

I am not a lawyer (and you should get one, if you are concerned about possible legal issues), so you probably would not interested in my opinion about that, but I really do not understand *why it bothers you*.

[Copyleft](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/) of [GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) protects [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) against becoming bound with additional restrictions, not the otherwise.

Since both of modern¹ BSD Licenses ([2-clause](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:FreeBSD) and [3-clause](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:BSD_3Clause)) are *compatible* with GNU GPL, i. e. their sets of restrictions are subsets of that of GNU GPL, it is nothing wrong to combine *your code* under the terms of one of them along with GPL’ed one in a single product. *As a whole* for the sake of simplicity it might and should be considered as covered by GNU GPL, but that by no means would affect copyright conditions your own part of work alone – it remains under terms of lax permissive license, your chose for it.

---

<sup>¹ I hope, you are not going to use [4-clause](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:BSD_4Clause) BSD License with [obnoxious](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/bsd.html) advertising clause.</sup>

Comment: GPL compatibility of a license means you can use BSD library in GPL project and release it under GPL.  It doesn't go both ways.  A GPL library can only be used in a GPL project - not a BSD project.  Given that the OP wants to release the program under BSD, suggesting GPLing it isn't the desired result.

Comment: @MichaelT Sorry, but it does not seems that you have carefully read what I’ve written. I did *not* suggest OP to cover *his* work by GNU GPL.

Comment: GPL demands [reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#Reciprocity), like the 'share alike' clause of Creative Commons, and BSD not endorse this demand. So, as @MichaelT says, a GPL project can use BSD code, because BSD don't cares, but a BSD cannot use GPL code because BSD don't follow GPL's restrictions.

Comment: @Cochise ‘a BSD cannot use GPL code’ – is some word (or words) missed here?

Comment: " a GPL project can use BSD code `[...]` a BSD `[project]` cannot use GPL code’. Sorry if the text was not clear.

Comment: @Cochise ① If you think that GNU GPL works somewhat differently according to whether part under compatible licence is dependant (main) or dependency, that’s the point you are mistaken in.

Comment: @Cochise ② You, of course, cannot grant more rights than you obtain so if you want to distribute a work, derived from two (or more) works under various compatible licences, as whole under a *single* licence you shall choose the *less* permissive one (of BSDL and GNU GPL, it would be GPL), but that is not specific to GNU GPL or copyleft (‘reciprocity’ if you will) at all – it’s a basic principle of copyright.

Comment: @Cochise ③ For example, if you combine in your project software covered by BSDL and Apache License and want to distribute it under a single licence, you shall do the very same – choose the less permissive of them, i. e. Apache License.

Comment: @Cochise ④ What copyleft licence does in addition to non-copyleft one is to protect work against being bound with more *restrictions*, but it does not (and actually *can not*) forbid you to grant more permissions for *your own* part of the work whatever it combined with.